# how to get data on all child in firebase realtime database android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase structure

[image]

```
    databaseSupp.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            suppList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot suppSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child("Task").getChildren()) {

                //Log.d("fbBee", dataSnapshot.getRef().child("Task").child("9223450").child("Firebase").toString());

                Log.d("fbBee", suppSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                Log.d("fbGet",suppSnapshot.child("Firebase").getValue().toString());
                Supp supp = suppSnapshot.child("Firebase").getValue(Supp.class);

                suppList.add(supp);

            }

            SuppList adapter = new SuppList(MainActivity2.this, suppList);
            mListViewSupp.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

This is my code, but this code just show child Firebase. I want read and show data from child Firebase, but I need flag on child Reply for reference in my fragmens. please help for code.

Comment: Need more details about what you want to do. How Supp.class does look like? And please check your grammar...

Comment: sorry for my bad english (:

Comment: @Dumbo Supp.class for setter and getter

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Task/");
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot taskNo : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // now you in (9223450)
            Object firebaseObj = taskNo.child("Firebase").getValue(FirebaseObj.class); //class with params set/get methods
            Object replayObj = taskNo.child("Replay").getValue(ReplayObj.class); //class with params set/get methods

            // ALTERNATIVE
            /*
            for (DataSnapshot child : taskNo.getChildren()) {
                if(child.getKey().equals("Firebase")) {
                    String address = child.child("Address").getValue(String.class);
                    String customer = child.child("Customer").getValue(String.class);
                    // ...
                } else if (child.getKey().equals("Replay")) {
                    // replay 
                    // ...
                }
            }
            */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
```

Comment: and why with this ?
SuppList adapter = new SuppList(MainActivity2.this, suppList);
mListViewSupp.setAdapter(adapter);

can it be one list data on constructor ?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. What for you are using an adapter?

Comment: im really sorry for my bad english. i use Supp.class for setter and getter, and SuppList.class for ArrayList and Constructor.  i want child Firebase and Reply can be one list to add for SuppList.

Comment: How your adapter look like?

Answer (score 0):

Like This

public class SuppList extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private Activity context;
private List<Supp> suppList;

public SuppList (Activity context, List<Supp> suppList){

    super(context, R.layout.list_layout_new, suppList);
    this.context = context;
    this.suppList = suppList;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_new, null, true);

    TextView textViewSo = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewSo);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    TextView textViewAddress = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);

    Supp supp = suppList.get(position);
    textViewSo.setText(supp.getSuppId());
    //Log.e("SuppTest", supp.getSuppId());
    textViewName.setText(supp.getSuppName());
    textViewAddress.setText(supp.getSuppAddress());

    return listViewItem;

}
```

}

Comment: @Dumbo like this